# resize uisearchdisplaycontroller width when click cancel button

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, cancel-button, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I want to change width of uisearchDisplaycontroller when click cancel. i add my code for reference...

```
mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
[mySearchBar setDelegate:self];
resName_search = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
resName_search.delegate = self;
resName_search.searchResultsDataSource = self;
resName_search.searchResultsDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:resName_search.searchBar];
[resName_search.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 106.0, 40.0)];
```

it displays good...but when i search item and then click cancel button... it does not resize ..

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
   btnCuisine.hidden =YES;
   btnService.hidden =YES;
   imgDropDwn1.hidden =YES;
   imgDropDwn2.hidden =YES;
   [resName_search.searchBar  setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
   [resName_search.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 320.0, 40.0)];
   return YES;
  } 
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
   NSLog(@"size changed 106.0");
   [resName_search.searchBar  setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
   [resName_search.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 106.0, 40.0)];
   btnCuisine.hidden =NO;
   btnService.hidden =NO;
   imgDropDwn1.hidden =NO;
   imgDropDwn2.hidden =NO;
  }
```

i also add image link for that problem plz refer that solve my problem  [image Link](http://iosstoryboard.blogspot.in/2014/10/uisearchdisplaycontroller-problem.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES and setActive to NO. but  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES is not important i think...

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
 NSLog(@"size changed 106.0");
 self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
 [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
 [resName_search.searchBar  setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
 [resName_search.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 106.0, 40.0)];
// mySearchBar.frame =CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 106.0, 40.0);
btnCuisine.hidden =NO;
btnService.hidden =NO;
imgDropDwn1.hidden =NO;
imgDropDwn2.hidden =NO;
}
```

tap on Background of table while searching searchbar not resize So add searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch delegate

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
NSLog(@"size changed 106.0");
//    [resName_search.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
[resName_search.searchBar  setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
//    [self.view addSubview:resName_search.searchBar];
[resName_search.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 106.0, 40.0)];
//    mySearchBar.frame =CGRectMake(0.0, barOriginY+79.0, 106.0, 40.0);
btnCuisine.hidden =NO;
btnService.hidden =NO;
imgDropDwn1.hidden =NO;
imgDropDwn2.hidden =NO;
}
```